# Which collection does not implement IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, collections, ienumerable

Is there any type of collection under `System.Collections` that does not inherit from `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`?

I need an example.

Comment: Take a look for yourself: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Out of interest, why?

Comment: I doubt there is a collection that doesn't implement `IEnumerable`

Comment: @DannyChen Even though your namespace has the same name, it's still a different namespace than `global::System.Collections` ;)

Comment: @Sean For your interest I was reading this: "In C#, it is not strictly necessary for a collection class to inherit from IEnumerable and IEnumerator in order to be compatible with foreach" in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288462(v=vs.71).aspx Then I wondered which collection does not inherit from `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No class *directly* inside `System.Collections` will implement `IEnumerable<T>` - that namespace predates generics in .NET - however the classes which could roughly be defined "Collections" in that namespace all implement `IEnumerable`

- ArrayList
- BitArray
- CollectionBase
- DictionaryBase
- Hashtable
- Queue
- ReadOnlyCollectionBase
- SortedList
- Stack

If we expand to "Any namespace below `System.Collections`" we get into `System.Collections.Generic` and `System.Collections.ObjectModel` and `System.Collections.Specialized` - all the collections classes inside them implement `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<T>` or both.

Comment: Also note that even System.Array implements IEnumerable.

Comment: Also string inherit IEnumerable (common gotcha).